# GoLang Binary Tree - using Interface and Struct

Tags: go

I am trying to use Interfaces and Struct in GoLang to create a binary tree concept

I wrote the below code

```
package main

import "fmt"

type node interface {
    add(a int)
    getval() int
}

type node_element struct {
    element int

    left  *node
    right *node
}

func (c *node_element) add(a int) {
    c.element = a
}

func (c *node_element) getval() int {
    return c.element
}

func main() {

    var s node

    s = &node_element{}

    s.add(1)

    fmt.Println(s.getval())

}
```

Now how do I instantiate left and right. I am using VIM with Go autocomplete. In auto complete on pressing . there is no list. Which means access to this pointer object to s is not happening

How to instantiate and use left and right ?

Comment: Read through ["Effective Go"](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) for a quick overview on the language and programming style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to declare `s` as a `node`, a `*node_element` can be used as a `node`. You also never want to have a pointer to an interface, so change the `left` and `right` types to `node`.

You can then just assign the fields directly:

```
s := &node_element{}
s.add(1)
s.left = &node_element{element: 2}
s.right = &node_element{element: 3}
```

Comment: If I continue in this program to make a binary tree program out of it, just want to understand how would I know if the s.left element is already declared or not ?

Comment: @tahseenjamal: just compare it to `nil`.

Comment: if I try to now print

s.left.element

it gives me error, why ?

Comment: `left` is a `node`, not a `node_element `. You need a type assertion if you want to do that.

Comment: Got it. Now the last thing. I want to show binary tree. Which means in getval() want to return a string showing left and right also

but in first initialisation left and right are nil and therefore 

return "{" + strconv.Itoa(c.left.(*node_element).element) + "." + strconv.Itoa(c.element) + "." + strconv.Itoa(c.right.(*node_element).element) + "}"

fails as am converting a nil to string

Comment: you need to check if it's nil before the type assertion, or you need to use the  multi-value type assertion which is safe from panics.